# Typing on Canvas with HTML input?

Tags: html, text, input, html5-canvas

I have some JS with `context.fillText("TEXT HERE", 0, 0);` and it allows me to lay some text over an image I have loaded into Canvas.

Is it possible to use an input field to type into and allow this fill in the text for `context.fillText`?

```
<form>
Text here: <input type="text" name="texthere">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[absolutely](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/v29Qe/)**, have an observer on your text field, and re-paint the canvas with the new text entered:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
    ctx = null,
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], th;

th = document.querySelector('#texthere');
th.onkeyup = function() {
    if (ctx) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillText(th.value, 20, 20);
    }
}

if (canvas.getContext('2d')) {
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
}
```